# Object detection with Tensorflow and galeone/tfgo

Tags: python, tensorflow, go, object-detection

What i have:

- a trained and exported model for object detection, trained by this script [model_main_tf2.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py) and exported by this script [exporter_main_v2.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/exporter_main_v2.py)
- python code for inference (i found this snippet on stackowerflow), and it seems works well with my model

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils

detect_fn = tf.saved_model.load("exported-models/my_model/saved_model")
print(detect_fn)
PATH_TO_LABELS = 'annotations/label_map.pbtxt'
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)
IMAGE_PATHS = ["img.png"]
def load_image_into_numpy_array(path):
    return np.array(Image.open(path))

for image_path in IMAGE_PATHS:
    print('Running inference for {}... '.format(image_path), end='')
    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np)
    input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                   for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()
    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np_with_detections,
          detections['detection_boxes'],
          detections['detection_classes'],
          detections['detection_scores'],
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          max_boxes_to_draw=200,
          min_score_thresh=.6,
          agnostic_mode=False)
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
    plt.imshow(image_np_with_detections)
    # graph.png contains img.png and detected object within rectangle and label
    plt.savefig("graph.png")
```

- golang snippet for inference whitch loads same model, but it's not working, this code panics with `op detection_boxes not found`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    tf "github.com/galeone/tensorflow/tensorflow/go"
    tg "github.com/galeone/tfgo"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    model := tg.LoadModel("saved_model", []string{"serve"}, nil)

    imageBytes, err := os.ReadFile("img.png")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    tensor, err := tf.NewTensor(imageBytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    results := model.Exec([]tf.Output{
        model.Op("detection_boxes", 0),
        model.Op("detection_scores", 0),
        model.Op("detection_classes", 0),
        model.Op("num_detections", 0),
    }, map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
        model.Op("image_tensor", 0): tensor,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //TODO
    fmt.Print(results)
}
```

Indeed, there are no such operations in `operations`

```golang
model, _ := tf.LoadSavedModel("saved_model", []string{"serve"}, nil)
operations := model.Graph.Operations() // no 'detection_boxes' and others
```

So, whats wrong with my Go code, or maybe it's my model issue?

P.S. originally i posted this question on [Github Issues](https://github.com/galeone/tfgo/issues/85), then realised stackoverflow is better place